# If $V(x)$ is positive definite, then $\Omega_c$ is bounded

Tags: positive-definite

$x(t)$ satisfies the ODE: $\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=f(x)$, $f$ is a local Lipschitz map $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. $V(x):\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a positive definite and continuously differentiable function. Denote $\Omega_C=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : V(x) \le c \}$, where $c>0$. Is the following statement true and how to prove it?

> If $\frac{d}{dt}V(x) \le 0$ in $\Omega_c$, then $\Omega_c$ is bounded for sufficiently small $c>0$.

Note: A function $V: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called positive defnite if $V(0)=0$ and $V(x) > 0, ~x\ne 0$.

Comment: Do you know anything else about $V$? Continuity...? I shoudl note that, as stated, the question is definitely not true.

Comment: Even differentiability will not help: Think of a continuous bimodal distribution with $0$ being the unique minimizer.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Please see the new edit.

Comment: @max_zorn Please see the new edit.

Comment: What is $f$? Notice that $\Omega_c$ does not depend on $t$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri new edit

Comment: If $f$ is locally Lipschitz, but not globally so, then the solution $x$ need not exist everywhere.

Comment: The question is ill posed. Do you mean to say perhaps: "Suppose there is some $k>0$ such that $\frac{d}{dt}V(x(t))\leq 0$ in $\Omega_k$. Is it true that there is some $c>0$ such that $\Omega_c$ is bounded?"

Comment: Moreover, $V(x(t))$ is defined in (a subset) of $\mathbb R$, so to say that $\frac{d}{dt}V(x(t))\leq 0$ in $\Omega_k$ is nonsensical.